# What happens and what do we observe during this qualitative analysis of bronze?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

What is the observation when we add $\ce{HNO3}$ to bronze followed by addition of dilute HCl and bubbling of $\ce{H2S}$ gas through it.

Please tell the inferences as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sorts of bronze. The most widely known is an alloy copper $\ce{Cu}$ and tin $\ce{Sn}$. When dissolved in nitric acid $\ce{HNO3}$, copper is oxidized into a blue solution containing $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ion. Metallic tin $\ce{Sn}$ is not dissolved. It is transformed into an insoluble and colorless oxide $\ce{SnO2}$ which often makes a gel difficult to filtrate. So the gel has often a blue color after filtration, but this is due to the presence of $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ion in the gel. If now you pass $\ce{H2S}$ in the blue $\ce{Cu^2+}$ solution, it will precipitate and make a black and heavy precipitate $\ce{CuS}$.